# Is it possible to allow only random opponents in an iOS Game Center game?

Tags: ios, game-center

I am creating an iOS game that relies on the opponents not being able to collaborate to win.  Therefore I want to minimise the possibility that they can communicate with their opponent to game the system.  Is it possible in Game Center to only allow players to start matches against random opponents or is playing your friends so ingrained into Game Center that I won't be able to prevent them from starting matches against their friends?